# Getting null values in REST web service PUT command

Tags: web-services, rest, put

I am writing a PUT request REST web service. I have a POJO User.java having String name. Below is my POJO:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "User") 
public class User implements Serializable { 
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        private String Name;

public String getName() {
    return Name;
}

public void setName(String Name) {
    this.Name = Name;
}

public User() {

}

public User(String Name) {
    this.Name = Name;
}   
}
```

My Web service is as below:

```
@Path("/user")
public class UserService {
@Path("/xml")
@PUT
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
public User putUsers(User user){
    System.out.println("***** Received User XML *****");
    System.out.println("Name :: "+user.getName());      
    return user;
}
}
```

From Postman, i am sending below in Request body:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><User>
<Name>abcd</Name></User>
```

and PUT URL executed:

http://localhost:8080/rest/users/xml

But i am getting null as output:

```
***** Received User XML *****
Name :: null
```

Why am i not getting abcd as output?

Answer (score 0):

Ok.. i found the answer..
1) I just added @XmlElement(name = "Name") above the getter getName().
2) Changed it to small n in the variable declaration Name as 'name'.

This fixed it.